# JavaScript vs JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS optimisation problem.

```
// JavaScript Document

window.onload = function (){
    setInterval (function (){ 
        var GetMeId = document.getElementsByClassName("prev")[0].getAttribute("id");
        var StyleFor = "display:block; width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left:0; transition:4s;";
        $('.layer').removeAttr('style'); // еSIXаный костыль для упрощения кода.
        /*
        document.getElementsByClassName("layer")[0].removeAttribute("style");
        document.getElementsByClassName("layer")[1].removeAttribute("style");
        document.getElementsByClassName("layer")[2].removeAttribute("style");
        document.getElementsByClassName("layer")[3].removeAttribute("style");
        document.getElementsByClassName("layer")[4].removeAttribute("style");
        document.getElementsByClassName("layer")[5].removeAttribute("style");
        document.getElementsByClassName("layer")[6].removeAttribute("style");
        */
        if(document.getElementById(GetMeId) != document.getElementById("p"+GetMeId)) {
            document.getElementById("p"+GetMeId).setAttribute("style",StyleFor);
        }
    },1000);
};
```

How can I remove JQuery from this piece of code?

Comment: Do you mean how to do this without jquery?

Comment: Please include the HTML  in your question.

Comment: "You mean how to do this without jquery? – Roquey"
yep.

Comment: @AlexChar jQuery is a library.

Comment: You've already done what you need (commented out, though). What is the actual problem? Doing this in a loop?

Comment: "Yes. jquery is javascript" - mb framework?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, please read [MCVE] there was only *one* line that was actually relevant and the rest fluff.

Comment: @AlexChar I am still not sure why you had this comment. But what I meant is that jQuery *is not* JavaScript. JQuery is written in JavaScript, but you do not need jQuery to write good JavaScript. Too many developers cannot use JS without jQuery. And I do not think it is a good thing, especially as today, most of the time, [jQuery is useless](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Comment: @Roque I removed my comments. There is no need to argue here. We can discuss it if you want in the chat :)

Answer (score 0):

There, no jQuery. Not sure your code will be much more optimised though. jQuery is not a big overload.

```
window.onload = function (){
    setInterval (function (){ 
        var GetMeId = document.getElementsByClassName("prev")[0].getAttribute("id");
        var StyleFor = "display:block; width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left:0; transition:4s;";
        var layers = document.getElementsByClassName('layer');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(layers, function(layer){
          layer.removeAttribute("style");
        });
        if(document.getElementById(GetMeId) != document.getElementById("p"+GetMeId)) {
            document.getElementById("p"+GetMeId).setAttribute("style",StyleFor);
        }
    },1000);
};
```